# html5 animation with spritesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, sprite-sheet

```
let globalCanvas;
let globalCtx;

class ScratchCard {
  constructor(canvasSelector, revealThreshold) {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector(canvasSelector);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    globalCanvas = this.canvas;
    globalCtx = this.ctx;
    this.revealThreshold = revealThreshold;
    this.isDrawing = false;
    this.bounds = globalCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.overlayCleared = false;
    this.initCanvasSize();

    this.scratchImage = new Image();
    this.scratchImage.src = "./chairman-scratchedbg.c51180af71dc732a9dbf.png";
    this.scratchImage.onload = () => this.initCanvasWithImage();

    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  initCanvasSize() {
    globalCanvas.width = globalCanvas.clientWidth;
    globalCanvas.height = globalCanvas.clientHeight;
  }

  initCanvasWithImage() {
    globalCtx.drawImage(
      this.scratchImage,
      0,
      0,
      globalCanvas.width,
      globalCanvas.height
    );
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    globalCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      this.isDrawing = true;
    });

    globalCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      this.isDrawing = false;
      this.checkIfRevealed();
    });

    globalCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      const x = e.clientX - this.bounds.left;
      const y = e.clientY - this.bounds.top;
      if (this.isDrawing) {
        this.clearOverlay(e);
      }
      this.checkIfRevealed();
    });

    globalCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
      this.isDrawing = true;
    });

    globalCanvas.addEventListener("touchend", () => {
      this.isDrawing = false;
      this.checkIfRevealed();
    });

    globalCanvas.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => {
      if (this.isDrawing) {
        const touch = e.touches[0];
        this.clearOverlay(touch);
      }
      this.checkIfRevealed();
    });

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      this.initCanvasSize();
      this.initCanvasWithImage();
    });
  }

  clearCanvas() {
    globalCtx.clearRect(0, 0, globalCanvas.width, globalCanvas.height);
  }

  clearOverlay(e) {
    const x = e.clientX - this.bounds.left;
    const y = e.clientY - this.bounds.top;

    globalCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    globalCtx.beginPath();
    globalCtx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    globalCtx.fill();
  }

  checkIfRevealed() {
    const imageData = globalCtx.getImageData(
      0,
      0,
      globalCanvas.width,
      globalCanvas.height
    );
    const pixels = imageData.data;
    let transparentPixels = 0;

    for (let i = 3; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
      if (pixels[i] === 0) {
        transparentPixels++;
      }
    }

    const totalPixels = globalCanvas.width * globalCanvas.height;
    const revealPercentage = transparentPixels / totalPixels;

    if (revealPercentage >= this.revealThreshold && !this.overlayCleared) {
      this.overlayCleared = true;
      this.clearCanvas();
      startSpriteAnimation();
    }
  }
}

class SpriteAnimation {
  constructor(canvas, ctx) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.spriteWidth = 207;
    this.spriteHeight = 200;
    this.offsetX = (this.canvas.width - this.spriteWidth) / 2;
    this.offsetY = (this.canvas.height - this.spriteHeight) / 2;
    this.frame = 0;
    this.timer = 0;
    this.markedForDeletion = false;
    this.animationFrameId = null;
    this.ballAnimation = new Image();
    this.ballAnimation.src = "./loading_animation.png";
  }

  startAnimation() {
    this.animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }

  animate() {
    this.timer++;
    if (this.timer % 5 === 0) {
      this.frame++;
    }
    if (this.frame > 8) {
      this.frame = 0;
    }

    this.draw();
    this.animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }

  draw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.ctx.drawImage(
      this.ballAnimation,
      this.frame * this.spriteWidth,
      0,
      this.spriteWidth,
      this.spriteHeight,
      this.offsetX,
      this.offsetY,
      this.spriteWidth,
      this.spriteHeight
    );
  }

  stopAnimation() {
    if (this.animationFrameId) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationFrameId);
    }
  }
}

function startSpriteAnimation() {
  const spriteAnimation = new SpriteAnimation(globalCanvas, globalCtx);
  spriteAnimation.startAnimation();
}

const scratchCard = new ScratchCard(".scratch-area", 0.3);
```

i am trying to make the animation start when all the scratched area is cleared. in fact the animation function is being called but when the cover is all cleared the animation is not starting until i click on control + or control - (minimize or maximize the screen ) i dont know where i did something wrong. can someone help me?

Comment: Can you draw something else in the SpriteAnimation try circles or squares?  is the problem with the image (ballAnimation) or that draw function not been called at all?

Comment: my gut feeling is telling me this is something with the loading of the image, in one class you have `this.scratchImage.onload = () => this.initCanvasWithImage();` but not on the other, that worries me a bit

Comment: Check the load status of the sprite sheet. Simple solution in `SpriteAnimation.draw` after the clear add `if (this.ballAnimation.complete) { this.ctx.drawImage(this.ballAnimation, this.frame * this.spriteWidth,... and so on`. Note complete only tells you if the load sequence has completed. It does not indicate if it was successful. You should use the `Image.onload` event to check if the image has loaded and either start the animation on load or define a semaphore to indicate that it is safe to draw the image in the draw call..